# How to change "/" in the first word with function if it has 3 words and 2 words are invalid

Tags: javascript

I have 3 variables

```
let oneWord = "offering" 
let twoWord = "test_offering"  
let threeWord = "loan_offering_data"
```

I want to make where if the value of TwoWord is executed/displayed as **test-offering** and suppose the value of threeWord is executed/displayed it becomes **loan/offering-data**

**how to make a function to meet the above criteria dynamic?**

Comment: what do you mean by executed? I'm lost at "if the value of TwoWord is executed/displayed as test-offering"

Answer (score 0):

```
function reformat(word) {
    const wds=word.split("_");
    if (wds.length ===1) return word;
    if (wds.length ===2) return wds.join("-");
    if (wds.length ===3) return `${wds[0]}/${wds[1]}-${wds[2]}`;
    throw new Error("too many words");
}
```